# rebuilding sets and intersection in python

Tags: python, set, intersection, rebuild, preserve

I have the following problem, initially I have 3 sets:

```
A [1,2,3],B [2,3,4,5] and C [2,5,6,7]
```

I next consider the intersection of sets two by two and the intersection of all of them

```
AB [2,3],
AC [2],
BC [2,5] and
ABC [2] (Full intersection)
```

Now what I want is a new reordering of my sets with the following conditions:
1. preserve the cardinality of each set.
2. preserve the cardinality of all possible intersections.

for example I should get

```
A [3,4,7],
B [1,3,7,5] and
C [2,6,5,7]
```

Notice that the new intersection of A and B (now [3,7]) has 2 elements as in the previous intersection, analogously with intersections AC ,BC and full intersection ABC and of course, the cardinality of A, B and C continue to be 3, 4 and 4 respectively. 
Finally I need to do that process of reorganizing as many times as possible, which I understand depends on the cardinality of the sets and the total number of sets.

Comment: This is an algorithm question and should be tagged for that.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: in fact the problem is bigger and my proposed solution is the one I described. Finding all the possible intersections is my idea, now building the new groups is the part that I can't implement

Comment: Why not generate a list with the elements of A, B and C, compute all possible permutations, slice the lists into sets of initial lengths if all checks pass?

Comment: generate the list of all the elements and try to build the sets from it but do not get to preserve the cardinality of the intersections with the elements in the intersection is greater than the initial or sometimes it is zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just generate all possible permutations of your original set of elements, and use them as "mappings" from the original elements to a new configuration. So for example, `2345671` maps each number to the next and wraps around; this creates the sets:

```
A = {2, 3, 4}    # from {1, 2, 3}
B = {3, 4, 5, 6} # from {2, 3, 4, 5}
C = {3, 6, 7, 1} # from {2, 5, 6, 7}
```

This is pretty straightforward to do using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import permutations

def all_configurations(*sets):
    elements = list(set.union(*sets))
    for perm in permutations(elements):
        map = {old: new for old, new in zip(elements, perm)}
        new_sets = [{map[k] for k in old_set} for old_set in sets]
        yield new_sets


A = {1, 2, 3}
B = {2, 3, 4, 5}
C = {2, 5, 6, 7} 

confs = all_configurations(A, B, C)
for conf in confs:
    print(conf)
    # Or: Ax, Bx, Cx = conf
```

Note how I used a `yield` statement, this will generate each new permutation one at a time instead of creating them all at once, so you can use this for larger numbers of elements without blowing up your memory. Also, the function as written will work for any number of input sets.

Of course, this will definitely generate some duplicates (e.g. in your example, mapping 6 to 7 and 7 to 6 doesn't change anything) but it should also certainly generate every valid option. Some sample outputs:

```
[{2, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 6, 7}]
[{4, 5, 7}, {1, 3, 4, 7}, {2, 3, 6, 7}]
[{3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 3, 4, 7}]
[{1, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 4, 7}, {2, 3, 5, 7}]
```

---

**EDIT**: In order to get a fixed number of non-duplicate arrangements, you can change the original code to return a `tuple` of `frozensets` instead of a list of sets, that way the whole thing can hashed so you only get uniques. You can then just add things to the output set until it reaches your desired cardinality:

```
from itertools import permutations

def all_configurations(*sets):
    elements = list(set.union(*sets))
    for perm in permutations(elements):
        map = {old: new for old, new in zip(elements, perm)}
        new_sets = tuple(frozenset(map[k] for k in old_set) for old_set in sets)
        yield new_sets

def n_configurations(n, *sets):
    output = set()
    confs = all_configurations(*sets)
    for conf in confs:
        output.add(conf)
        if len(output) >= n:
            break
    return output


A = {1, 2, 3}
B = {2, 3, 4, 5}
C = {2, 5, 6, 7} 

confs = n_configurations(10, A, B, C)
for a, b, c in confs:
    print(a, b, c)
```

This produces the following 10 configurations:

```
(frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 5, 6]), frozenset([2, 4, 6, 7]))
(frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 4, 6]), frozenset([2, 5, 6, 7]))
(frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 6, 7]), frozenset([2, 4, 5, 7]))
(frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 4, 6]), frozenset([2, 4, 5, 7]))
(frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 4, 5]), frozenset([2, 4, 6, 7]))
(frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 5, 6]), frozenset([2, 4, 5, 7]))
(frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 4, 7]), frozenset([2, 5, 6, 7]))
(frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 4, 5]), frozenset([2, 5, 6, 7]))
(frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 4, 7]), frozenset([2, 4, 5, 6]))
(frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 5, 7]), frozenset([2, 4, 6, 7]))
```

Comment: the proposal seems great to me! only in my real case I have approximately 50 groups and in each group there are approximately between 100 and 300 elements. When I apply your idea it works if but depending on the number of groups and sizes it could be a long process, would there be any way to improve that?

Comment: How could I modify its code so that it does not give me all the possible permutations but a fixed number. In the example we have approximately 5040 new groups (you showed me 4) I would like to be able to obtain, for example, 200 new groups or any number less than the total and that those groups are shown clearly. Thanks!

Comment: @Herberth You can make a set of the output sets and stop adding things to it once it's got as many elements as you want. See my edited answer.

Comment: it's great! only now that I realized, for example in the 10 configurations that you show the first set {1,2,3} in all cases it is the same (I know that in general each line is a new configuration, I agree) but I would like some randomness. It is possible to randomly choose N permutations and therefore show the N corresponding configurations ?.
I understand that so far we are taking the first n configurations generated by the first n permutations.

Comment: For example, in the first configuration that was shown to me, there is a certain randomness in the first sets of each configuration.                          [{2, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 6, 7}]
[{4, 5, 7}, {1, 3, 4, 7}, {2, 3, 6, 7}]
[{3, 5, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, {2, 3, 4, 7}]
[{1, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 4, 7}, {2, 3, 5, 7}]

Comment: @Herberth you could just generate the full set and then randomly sample from those. That's sort of what I did in the four that I selected to display. It will, however, slow things down since you'll need to generate the full set first. You could instead try using `random.shuffle` to generate permutations one at a time, as long as they're being added to a `set` at the end you'll still make sure they're unique. If you want to generate all configurations you'd  rather do it the way I originally described though.

Comment: I share your same idea, I followed your advice, you helped me a lot, I really appreciate your proposal in very good! Thank you @tzaman

Answer (score 0):

Can this get you started?

```python
    import random
    import itertools


    def same_intersect_len(x, y, z):
        return (len(x & y) == len(a & b) and
                len(x & z) == len(a & c) and
                len(z & y) == len(b & c) and
                len(x & y & z) == len(a & b & c))


    a = set(random.sample(range(0, 10), 1))
    b = set(random.sample(range(0, 10), 2))
    c = set(random.sample(range(0, 10), 3))

    elements = list(a) + list(b) + list(c)

    ps = set(itertools.permutations(elements))
    new_a = list()
    new_b = list()
    new_c = list()
    for p in ps:
        candidate_a = {p[len(a) - 1]} - a
        candidate_b = set(p[len(a):len(a) + len(b) - 1]) - b
        candidate_c = set(p[len(a) + len(b):len(a) + len(b) + len(c) - 1]) - c
        if same_intersect_len(
                candidate_a,
                candidate_b,
                candidate_c):
            new_a.append(candidate_a)
            new_b.append(candidate_b)
            new_c.append(candidate_c)
```

Comment: of course! now for a general case I mean n groups and each group with m elements would be the next step